# Output file stored in VARBINARY column with Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pymssql

I have Flask frontend project and I use flask-sqlalchemy with pymssql database.
There is existing .net tool that saves files to `varbinary(max)` column in sql server db and it can download files too just fine.
Now I need flask view to output those files from `varbinary(max)` column.

I currently have the following code

```
// in model 

content = db.Column(VARBINARY())

// in view
query = models.File.query

f = query.filter(models.File.request_id == request_id).first_or_404()

response = Response(f.content, content_type='application/pdf')
response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment;filename={0}".format(file_name)

return response
```

Files are mostly pdfs and sample pdf is working just fine, but normal pdf files are corrupted, and I know they are ok in db, as .net client download them just fine.

So how to tweak `f.content` encoding so user would be able to open mentioned pdfs ?

Interesting that type(f.content) is returning 'str' so I belive flask-sqlalchemy internally converts array of bytes to string.

Comment: Is it in how you're using Flask, or in how you're using SQLAlchemy? Have you tried making a script that just using SQLAlchemy to save then retrieve the PDF from the database? That might help limit what the issue actually is.

Comment: @MarkHildreth I'll put more details in question. I'm saving file with `.net` and only trying to output it with flask-sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured that out.

Code I have was correct, and it outputs file in a right format.

Problem was with freedts driver, it has limit of 64512 bytes in freedts.conf

```
text size = 64512
```

Changing it to something more sane fixes the error.